# Java : garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

i was asked a question regarding garbage collection in one interview.

Below is the piece of code.

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("one");
    a.add("two");
    a.add("three");
    a.add("four");

HashSet<String> h=new HashSet<String>();
h.add("four");
h.add("five");
h.add("six");

h.addAll(a);
a=null;
```

Question is : how many objects are eligible for garbage collection>

Please explain.

Comment: IMO the only correct answer is: *impossible to tell*. :-) We don't know how many objects are created internally by `String`, `HashSet` and  `ArrayList`.

Comment: Another reason it's impossible to tell is that nothing is being said explicitly about the precise time when the question is to be evaluated.  Right after the last assignment, or when the method has finished ?

Comment: @NPE Actually, we do, at least with openjdk. The only user-visible GC-eligible object is the ArrayList, which [allocated a single](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0DEFAULT_CAPACITY) `Object[10]`. So the answer is two.

Comment: Yet another reason it's impossible to tell is because in principle, you don't know whether or not the ArrayList constructor registers any new object in some kind of secretly kept cache or so.

Comment: It is typical of all these exam and interview questions that they require a lot of assumption before becoming factually answerable.

Answer (score 3):

General answer for the visible objects in the local scope: Only the `ArrayList`. The `HashSet` is reachable through the in-scope local variable `h` and the strings are reachable through the `HashSet`. Only objects that aren't reachable are eligible for garbage collection.

Notes:

1. String literals specifically may be allocated in the string pool, as mentioned in the comment. In that case, these objects will not be eligible for garbage collection.
2. Objects that are only reachable through special kinds of references (like weak references) may still be eligible.
3. Take this whole thing with a grain of salt, because this is a theoretical interview question on a subject that's complicated in practice. For example, you don't know what other objects are allocated behind the scenes. Or there may be an aggressive GC that collects objects even when they are (from the perspective of the language) reachable, if it can prove that there's no other usage of them.

Comment: Actually, the Strings will be placed in the String pool (literals), So the second part of your answer is partially valid.

Comment: @TheLostMind depending on the version of JVM strings will be either in string pool in permgen heap (never garbage collected) or in regular heap (since java 7). In regular heap they will be collected if no longer required.

Comment: @SimY4 - I know. Thats why I didn't down-vote or say that he is wrong. I was merely pointing out that he was *partially* valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("one"); --> "one" is added to the String constants pool and the reference is added to th arraylist
    a.add("two"); --> same as above
    a.add("three"); --> same as above
    a.add("four"); --> same as above
// 4 String literals in string pool, 4 references to them in the array list.

HashSet<String> h=new HashSet<String>();
h.add("four");--> "four" is added to the String constants pool and the reference is added to the hashSet
h.add("five");
h.add("six");
// even if you don't use h.addAll(), only 1 object i.e, a will be ready for GC once you set it to null because String literals in the constant pool cannot get GCed.
//h.addAll(a);
a=null;


PS : System.out.println(a.get(0) == "one"); returns true . same applies to elements of HashSet
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got

```
a = null;
```

and if there are no other objects holding references to the list or its containing objects, it would be eligible for garbage collection. Additionally know that there is no guarantee as to when the JVM will actually run garbage collection on it and free memory.